Need advice for Spring 6 migration strategy - Springboot, Spring Kafka, Spring batch
Our team manages a shared project repository (~300,000 lines of code) collaboratively maintained by approximately 15 very active developers. The repository includes:
Numerous Spring Boot APIs.
Common utility classes, models, services, constants, and other shared components, including testing.
Around 30 Spring Batch jobs.
Dependencies on Spring Kafka and other shared modules.
The Challenge:
We need to upgrade to Spring Boot 3 and Spring 6, including updating the Spring Batch framework. However, the newer versions introduce breaking changes and are not backward compatible. This poses a significant challenge because:
The repository is tightly coupled, with shared components heavily interdependent.
Development is continuous, and halting progress to complete the upgrade isn't feasible.
We recognize the lack of modularity in the codebase as a major weakness that exacerbates the issue. This happened over several years, when we did not expect this repo to grow this large and with the ongoing changes in the organization and the importance of getting the project across the line, this was the least of our problems.
Question:
What strategies or best practices can help us perform this upgrade seamlessly while maintaining development continuity?
We are open to restructuring the code to make it modular but are aware this might require extensive testing and multiple sprints, which may not align with our current capacity.
If you have faced similar challenges, what approach worked for you? Any insights, tools, or workflows that could help us plan and execute this transition effectively would be highly appreciated.

This site is designed to avoid open-ended discussion. Read the Help section before posting here.
